# control android device/emulator by python

Tags: android, python, android-emulator, appium, monkeyrunner

I am not familiar with android development. But just want to use python script to do something on my android device/emulator.
For example:

1. change system settings.
2. set a proxy.
3. open app A, click some place, do something else...
4. then open app B, tap up down,  do something else...
5. and so on.

I have tried

1. `monkeyrunner`, which actually is not by python(it's by Jython), and usually I don't know why the example code can't work(lack of debugging methods in this way.I can use ipython or pycharm if one support python),
2. `appium`, which introduce a very good framework, completely support python.But the tutorial always says about testing only one app, seems it can not change system settings or something like press `HOME` or `BACK` button.

I have never do such things before, are there any tools or tutorials could cover my case?

Comment: Appium does support device level settings / actions . I have already done this . like change system date/ time, turn on/off accessibility services from settings , open camera app and capture images etc

Comment: what system settings do you want to change and how do you setup a proxy in your case?

Comment: @ShekharSwami could you provide a tutorial about that?I really don't know how to get start.I am not a tester, but all the tutorial are for an app test.

Comment: @nullpointer  No specific, I just want a tool support device level settings / actions, because none of tutorial I found mentioned that.

Answer (score 8):

You can try [AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient) which provides also a UI (see [Culebra GUI](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/wiki/Culebra-GUI)) which allows you to do what you describe as your needs.

[image]
[image]